# XenDesktop create Catalog

Tags: powershell, citrix, xendesktop

Hi I'm using a script made by me and I try to use it to create a catalog in XenDesktop. And I don't know what is the error, really the XD answer say me that the error is to made 'random' the catalog, but, writing it there isn't any error.

I left the code

```
#
# CrearCatalogo.ps1
#

#Coger variables
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
   [string]$nombreCatalogo,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$tipoCatalogo,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$PVD
)

#Lanzar orden
$result = New-BrokerCatalog -name '$nombreCatalogo' -AllocationType '$tipoCatalogo' -MachinesArePhysical $false -ProvisioningType 'MCS' -SessionSupport 'SingleSession' -PersistUserChanges '$PVD' -AdminAddress "localhost:80"

   #Parsear
```

Now the error message (-AllocationType is the clue??)

New-BrokerCatalog : No se puede enlazar el parámetro 'AllocationType'. No se pu
ede convertir el valor "$tipoCatalogo" al tipo "Citrix.Broker.Admin.SDK.Allocat
ionType" porque hay valores no válidos en la enumeración. Especifique uno de lo
s valores de enumeración siguientes e inténtelo de nuevo. Los valores de enumer
ación posibles son "Permanent, Static, Random".
En C:\scripts\CrearGrupoEscritorios\01CrearCatalogo.ps1: 17 Carácter: 68
+ $result = New-BrokerCatalog -name '$nombreCatalogo' -AllocationType <<<<  '$t
ipoCatalogo' -MachinesArePhysical $false -ProvisioningType 'MCS' -SessionSuppor
t 'SingleSession' -PersistUserChanges '$PVD' -AdminAddress "localhost:80"
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-BrokerCatalog], Parame
   terBindingException

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I investigate this days and this is the solution

```
#Coger variables
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,Position=1)]
   [string]$nombreCatalogo,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [Citrix.Broker.Admin.SDK.AllocationType]$tipoCatalogo,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
   [string]$PVD
)

#Lanzar orden
New-BrokerCatalog –name "$nombreCatalogo" -AllocationType "$tipoCatalogo" –MachinesArePhysical $false –ProvisioningType 'MCS' –SessionSupport 'SingleSession' –PersistUserChanges "$PVD" -AdminAddress "localhost:80"

#Parsear
```

First change $tipoCatalogo class from string to Citrix.Broker.Admin.SDK.AllocationType and change ' to " in variables in the script command. And finally delete $result variable

Thanks for reading